# Cocoa: User Notifications never being delivered

Tags: cocoa, notifications, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to deliver a local notification, it looks something like this:

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
//set title, subtitle, and sound
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
```

But the notification doesn't appear. I know sometimes notifications are not presented if the app is frontmost but at the time of delivery it's not. In system preferences I made sure that notifications from my app are allowed, and I even overrode the userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification: method to always return YES but it still doesn't present the notification.

What is most confusing is that everything was working fine until I updated to Mavericks. I suppose something has changed in the update but I can't figure out what.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my guess is that something is `nil`. make sure you are either assigning a (valid and non-nil) `title`, or `informativeText`.

I imagine that having invalid values for other properties such as `otherButtonTitle` might prevent the notification from being displayed as well.

Are there any error messages in your console?

Use the debugger or `NSLog()` statements to assess the values assigned to the notification. You could also see this problem if the `NSUserNotification` pointer is nil (not the case from the code you posted, but worth mentioning).

Here is a minimal test for an app delegate that works on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSUserNotificationCenter* unc = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
    unc.delegate = self;

    NSUserNotification* notice = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
    notice.title = @"title"; // notifications need a title, or informativeText at minimum to appear on screen
    //notice.informativeText = @"informativeText";

    NSLog(@"notification: %@, notification center:%@", notice, unc);
    [unc deliverNotification:notice];
}

// The notifications will always dispaly even if we are in the foreground
- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I wasn't explicitly setting the "action button title name", Lion never caused me problems with this but apparently something's changed. Thanks!